# sudo NOPASSWD is ignored

Tags: arch-linux, sudo

I want to be able to run the `pm-suspend` and `pacman` without sudo to ask me for a password for all users in the group sudo.

I added the following line to my `/etc/sudoers` configuration following [this QA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246455/how-to-give-nopasswd-access-to-multiple-commands-via-sudoers):

```
%sudo ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/pm-suspend /usr/bin/gnome-session-quit
```

But it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Output of `id` please

Comment: I've never used Arch Linux, but according to the documentation, `pacman` can be used to install packages directly from user-supplied files. **Are you aware that you're essentially granting all users root permissions with this configuration?**

Answer (score 3):

You need to watch out for the following two points:

- sudo gives the highest priority to the **last matching configuration-line**
- you need to **separate different commands by ','**

so your configuration-line has to be

```
%sudo ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/pm-suspend, /usr/bin/gnome-session-quit
```

Comment: Man, thanks so much! I couldn't figure out it matches the last line. One headache less.